# Gettext PO file format

Tags: c++, c++11, gettext, po

I have some localization going on in the PO format. 
Is it possible to get the contents of this file within your C++ application? Instead of calling `gettext("id here")`
I want to read the complete file within C++ (on linux and windows)

Comment: It is possible but the PO file format is not that rigorously specified, (i.e. much less rigorous than the RFC that defined HTTP) which makes it a bit fiddly. Shameless plug, I made a C++11 header-only library that does this, which is available under boost license here: https://github.com/cbeck88/spirit-po

Comment: You could also use a C library called `libgettext-po` if you want to fully parse all the kinds of things that the GNU tools like `msgfmt` uses. My lib only is targeting the final part that's in your application.

Comment: @ChrisBeck how would one use those functions from the library? I'm getting errors while linking the executable: `undefined reference to 'po_file_read_v3'` I did include the file as following: `#include <gettext-po.h>`

Comment: `libgettext-po` is a C library, did you put `extern "C"` around the includes? Did you put the compiled lib in your linker path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely you can do this. PO file format is described in gettext's documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#PO-Files . You can use it to write your own parser for these files.

Gettext has also Windows version, you can use it if you are looking any gettext implementtaion for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm

Is there any other reason why you want to do this? Please give us more details.

Comment: This is either a comment or a link-only answer. Either way it's not a good answer. Please expand.